# Fix a position fixed element's right position to be the same regardless or whether or not the parent has a scrollbar

Tags: css, css-position

How can I force the `position: fixed;` element to always be exactly 16px from the `right` regardless of whether or not it's parent's content is overflowing or not?

```
<div style="overflow: auto; position: absolute; right: 0;">
 <div style="position: fixed; right: 0;">
  <div><span>Hide Something</span></div>
  <div><span>Show Something</span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding `position: absolute;` to the third element forces the position (e.g. `right: 16px;` or `right: 0;`) regardless of the (now grand) parent element's overflow or lack thereof.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; position: absolute; right: 0;">
 <div style="position: fixed; right: 0;">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 16px;"><span>Hide Something</span></div>
  <div><span>Show Something</span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this completely, but it seems that you should be able to set `right: 16px` to the `position: fixed` element.